# Why does my SSDT project build even though there is a missing function?

Tags: stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT project that has been working fine for some time. Recently a colleague removed a user defined function from the project and built it to find in which stored procedures the function was used and fix those stored procedures. After fixing those, she did a clean build of the project and then deployed to our database with success.

**The problem**

A few days later I discovered that there were still stored procedures using the old function that my colleague did not see because **the SSDT project still builds without warnings or errors**.

I verified on different computers with different versions of SSDT (including 16.4.1 released last week) and Visual Studio (2013 Update 4, 2015 Update 3) but it always builds without warnings.

I verified that:

1. the user defined function does not exist in the project or any referenced dacpacs and projects
2. all referenced dacpacs and projects have `Suppress Reference Warnings = False`
3. the sqlproj has the `Suppress TSql Warnings` setting empty
4. the 4 stored procedures having this problem have `Suppress TSql Warnings` setting empty and `Build Action = Build`

I thought SSDT existed in part to prevent such a thing from occurring. Can someone explain me **why does my SSDT project build even though there is a missing reference?**

Comment: What happens if you try to debug a call into the function? Does a warning show if you turn Code Analysis on?